# Add class on hover on Angular JS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to add a class when hovering the `li` element in the code below with Angular

```
<li ng-mouseenter="cola-selected=true" class="pull-left" ng-class="{'selected' : cola-selected}">
    <a href="interna.html">
        <img src="assets/images/cola.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

This is all the functionality the page will have, so I though maybe it is not necessarily to add a new js file for the js.

When the mouse enter to the `li` it should have the new class `selected`. The code above it is not working, and I cannot figure out why.

Here is an example of my code on a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mjrmeffc/

Comment: This tutorial should help you https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass If not, then I will write an answer shortly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why do you need an extra file if you can write the logic in your angular application?

I assume you make use of ng-app and have a so called javascript file where your logic is, and you should include it in here.

Here is an example of the proper way of adding/removing a class.

```
<div ng-app>
  <div 
    class="italic" 
    ng-class="{red: hover}" 
    ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
    ng-mouseleave="hover = false">
      Test 1 2 3.
  </div>
</div>
```

NB I found this in another stackoverflow question, please make proper use of google search first, I don't have enough reputation to flag your question, or to make a comment.

*** EDIT ***

It seems like you're not yet familiar with AngularJS. You need to include your 'app.js' or 'script.js' whatever you want to call it. In there you define your application using

```
var app = angular.module('yourappname', [/* add your dependencies here*/]);

//Other logic like controllers or services
```

And your HTML should be

```
<div ng-app="yourappname">
 <div ng-controller="yourController">
```

**PLEASE ORIENTATE YOURSELF FIRST BEFORE YOU START ASKING QUESTIONS**

Comment: I just copy your code, it seems to be the same as mine, however, I have the same issue, the red class is not added.

Comment: Can you please provide a codepen/jsfiddle or include your javascript file here?

Comment: I have updated my question with the link to jsfiddle

Comment: Why is there no Javascript? You need your angular application to use angular.

Comment: I have nothing else in angular, I just need to add this class

Comment: It work, apparently another problem is the hash in the variable name, that breaks the code too.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ng-mouseover` attr

```
<li ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" class="pull-left" ng-class="{{applyClass}}">
```

write a function `hoverIn()` in your script and assign value when hover over

```
$scope.hoverIn = function() {
    this.applyClass = "red";
}
```

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wRQ90dObSWtJFTWbASyj?p=preview)