# Changing the color of a specific h4 on hover

Tags: html, css

So I have the following div.

```
<div ng-click="showVideo(video)" class='video-Buttons'>
    <h4 style="text-align:left;"> {{video.Title}} </h4>
    {{video.Description}}
</div>
```

All My question is, is how would I change the color of that h4 on hover without changing other h4 around the site or is that even possible?
I know to change the h4 all it is is this.

```
h4:hover{
    color: blue;
}
```

But can I make it dive specific? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472352/add-class-on-hover-on-angular-js

Comment: Use  "div.video-Buttons h4:hover" in css selector instead of "h4:hover"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to the parent div of the h4 and then in css:

```
#ID h4:hover{
    //Whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: Thank you, don't know why I didn't think of an ID been a long morning. I'll accept your answer when it lets me

Comment: actually I've another question. If I wanted the h4 to be one color and text another color when I hover over the whole div how would I do that?

Comment: @JohnOC You want the background to be one colour and the text to be another?

Comment: No I already have background-color set that's fine. It's just I've a h4 and some text in the one div. I want the h4 to be blue and the rest of the text to be white

Comment: @JohnOC Just put some <p></p> around the text and set the colour to whatever you want

Comment: But see I want the <p> to change on hover too. See I want the div background color to be white with all text black. Then on hover I'm trying to make it so the background turns grey which is fine to do and then text inside <p> turns white and <h4> turns a light blue. Turning out to be more difficult than I thought it would be

Comment: @JohnOC By using the exact same technique as the answer it should work except replace the h4 with p

Answer (score 3):

Try using this,

```
.video-Buttons h4:hover{
    color: blue;
}
```

This will change any h4 colour to blue when it is under video.-Button class name

or else try this,

```
.video-Buttons > h4:hover{
    color: blue;
}
```

This will change only h4 colour to blue when it is a direct child of video.-Button class name.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no other h4s on the site which fall into this selector. You have a few options.

Option 1:

```
.video-Buttons h4:hover{
    color: blue;
}
```

Option 2:

```
div[ng-click="showVideo(video)"] h4:hover{
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use an Id over a class as the class could be used in more than one place

Comment: @JamesS You're not thinking cross-page, here. Yes, an ID could be used, but that ID could also be used elsewhere on another page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
h4:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: blue;
}
</style>

<h4 style="text-align:left;"> {{video.Title}} </h4>
```